# Put all parameters from a ini file section in var

Tags: python, ini

I create a program to configure a Debian server. This project is part of a school education to learn Python. The following code works but is too iterative and redundant. The goal is to create each variables for options in sections and put the value into it.

conf.ini :

```
[INTERFACES]
#Iface n°1 (enp0s3) :
IP1 = 192.168.3.1
NM1 = 255.255.255.0
GW1 = 192.168.3.254
#Iface n°2 (enp0s8) :
IP2 = 192.168.2.254
NM2 = 255.255.255.0
GW2 = 192.168.2.254
[NAT]
...
```

main.py :

```py
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('conf.ini')
IP1 = config.get('INTERFACES', 'IP1')
IP2 = config.get('INTERFACES', 'IP2')
IP3 = config.get('INTERFACES', 'IP3')
NM1 = config.get('INTERFACES', 'NM1')
NM2 = config.get('INTERFACES', 'NM2')
NM3 = config.get('INTERFACES', 'NM3')
GW1 = config.get('INTERFACES', 'GW1')
...
```

I was thinking of using a "for" loop to automate the creation of variables in a function but I can not find the solution i have something like that :

```py
import configparser
def fconfig():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('conf.ini')
    config.sections()
    ['INTERFACES', 'NAT', 'FIREWALL', 'DHCP']
    for option in config.sections():
        "creating the var i want"
```

But I misunderstand how can write it. How could I complete this correctly ?

Comment: `d = dict(config.items('INTERFACES'))`?

Comment: Please consider me as a beginner (I'm learning) if write this d will contain all the INTERFACES section I think, but i want to use the vars one by one in my programm so i need something like d1 = .... d2 = ..... d3 = ..... how could i get that ?

Comment: You generally *don't* want to do that. If you have groups of related variables, you want to keep them together in a container. You can use `d['IP1']` anywhere you were planning to use `IP1`. This is especially true when you *expect*, but don't necessarily know for a fact, that your config file will even *have* an `IP1` entry. Keep your data and your code separate.

Comment: Ok I understand thank you, so this is excatly what i need. But with that : `config.read('conf.ini')`
`d = dict(config.items('INTERFACES'))`
`print(d['IP1'])` I got : **KeyError: 'IP1'**

Comment: Hm; the `ItemView` object appears to lowercase the keys for some reason (I haven't read the docs closely enough to see if this is mentioned). You don't, however, need to build a new dict; `config['INTERFACES']['IP1']` works fine.